# Rotate Selection in Preview

Tags: macos, preview, graphics, copy-paste, image-editing

I am doing something I thought would be pretty easy, but apparently I was wrong.

I am wanting to edit blueprints for my sister-in-law's new bathroom redesign.  I have made selections to the PNG with my rectangle tool for the shower, sinks, toilette, doors, etc., etc.,

I simply want to rotate these selections (not the entire imagine) 90°.

Right clicking to rotate, does nothing.  Right clicking isn't allowed.

When I try to go to tools-rotate left with the selection selected it flips the entire imagine with the selection along with it.

I tried selecting the image, copying it to the clipboard and THEN rotating the imagine to get it to line up.  That too doesn't work as Preview clears clipboard every time I rotate the entire image.

Surely I cannot be the only person wanting to do this. I am running 10.11.6

Answer (score 11):

[image]

1. Copy the selection.
2. Open the selection in a new document.
3. Rotate the new document.
4. Select and copy the new document.
5. Paste the new document into the original.
6. Re-position.

Comment: If the target selection to be rotated is not flat (ie. you are able to move it independently around the larger image), it's possible to rotate this selection by using two fingers on a touchpad.

Comment: You can actually do this without creating a new document:
1. Rotate the original image;
2. Select & copy the rotated portion of the image you desire;
3. Undo the rotation from step 1;
4. Paste & re-position.